# clangd not finding gnu/stubs-32.h when using emscripten

Tags: cmake, emscripten, clangd

Clangd returns this error if I include anything when using a `compile_commands.json` generated by CMake
with flags from `emcc --cflags`.

Despite the error, the program compiles without any issue.

```
In included file: 'gnu/stubs-32.h' file not found clang (pp_file_not_found) [1, 10]
```

`src/CMakeLists.txt`

```
if(EMSCRIPTEN)
  execute_process(COMMAND emcc --cflags
      OUTPUT_VARIABLE EM_CFLAGS)
    set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "${EM_CFLAGS}")
endif()
```

`compile_commands.json`

```json
[
  {
    "directory": "/home/truff/.local/src/snake/em_build",
    "command": "/nix/store/6snfm5hzf45d88z6mw5msgdqrwwhnl30-emscripten-3.1.47/share/emscripten/emcc -I/home/truff/.local/src/snake/src/snake  -s USE_SDL=2 -target wasm32-unknown-emscripten -fignore-exceptions -fvisibility=default -mllvm -combiner-global-alias-analysis=false -mllvm -enable-emscripten-sjlj -mllvm -disable-lsr -DEMSCRIPTEN -Werror=implicit-function-declaration --sysroot=/home/truff/.local/src/snake/.cache/sysroot -resource-dir=/nix/store/ccsz1s9qvk46q2qs3lxjlsqyyg62l9sa-emscripten-llvm-3.1.47/lib/clang/16/ -idirafter/home/truff/.local/src/snake/.cache/sysroot/include -iwithsysroot/include/c++/v1 -Xclang -iwithsysroot/include/fakesdl -Xclang -iwithsysroot/include/compat\n -o src/CMakeFiles/snake.dir/Main.c.o -c /home/truff/.local/src/snake/src/Main.c",
    "file": "/home/truff/.local/src/snake/src/Main.c",
    "output": "src/CMakeFiles/snake.dir/Main.c.o"
  }
]
```

if I remove `-target wasm32-unknown-emscripten` the error goes away but the `__EMSCRIPTEN__` macro gets undefined.

I tried creating `./include/gnu/stubs-32.h` but it now creates

```
In included file: "This header is only meant to be used on x86 and x64 architecture" clang (pp_hash_error) [1, 10]
```

Comment: You might find the information in these issues filed by other users trying to use clangd with emscripten to be helpful: https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/1621, https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/1722